# Rule for factoring out variable in limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I am a bit confused about the proper way to calculate the limit of a function by factoring out the variable that strives for infinity.

If you have this:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \sqrt{x} \left(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}\right)$

for some reason you cannot do this:

$ = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \sqrt{x} \left(\sqrt{x(1+ \dfrac{1}{x})}-\sqrt{x}\right) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \sqrt{x} \left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}\right) = 0$

but rather should do this:

$ = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \sqrt{x} \frac{\left(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}\right)\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}\right)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \sqrt{x} \frac{x+1-x}{\left(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}\right)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x(1+\frac{1}{x})}+\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2}$

Why is it legit to factor out $x$ in the second approach but not in the first one? Is there a general rule for when you are allowed to do so and when not?

Comment: The problem isn't factoring, is applying limit in a subexpression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We look at the calculation at the end of the OP that you labelled as legitimate. It is in fact not legitimate, but happens to give the right answer. We **should not** write
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}+\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}.\tag{????}$$
For if we do that, we have let $x\to\infty$ in *part but not all* of our expression. We should instead do the correct algebraic manipulation (cancel the $\sqrt{x}$) and write
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}+\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+1}.$$
Now we can safely let $x\to\infty$, with full control over what is going on.

Comment: I upvoted this not only because it is right, but because for some reason or another someone downvoted you. This is the proper explanation. I was going to answer something similar to this until I read your post.

Comment: It seems that someone downvoted all the answers. One has to be understanding about these things. I get cranky when my blood nicotine level is too low. Perhaps the person had a toothache.

Comment: Perhaps so. This would at least be the most reasonable explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Although $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x} (3-3) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x} \cdot 0 =0$, in your case you have $\lim_{x \to \infty} = \sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x}) \neq \lim_x \sqrt{x} \cdot (\lim_x \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x})$ because $\infty \cdot 0 $ is an indeterminate form. Also $\lim_x (\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x}) \neq \lim_x \sqrt{x} - \lim_x \sqrt{x}$ because \infty - \infty is an indeterminate form too.